# Can I dynamically reference an object in java?

Tags: java, object, dynamic, reference, runtime

I'm working in a simulation environment called AnyLogic and it uses Java as its underlying code.

In my example, the user draws a flowchart and at runtime each element of the flowchart is instantiated. I can determine what the user has draw by the code:

```
           LinkedList eo = (LinkedList) this.getEmbeddedObjects();
```

- which returns a list of Strings representing the names of all the objects in the flowchart.

I would like to dynamically access these objects' methods but I'm new to Java and not sure how to go about this. From what I understand of reflection I can instantiate a classForName, but in this case I already have instantiated objects and I want to use the Strings to access them.

I am unsure how to proceed and appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Java reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) for the task.

This API is somewhat verbose though. If that's an issue, then you should go for one of the available [fluent](http://code.google.com/p/joor/) [reflection](http://fest.easytesting.org/reflect/apidocs/index.html) [APIs](http://projetos.vidageek.net/mirror/mirror/).

Comment: Thanks very much - this has been a great help to me! I've chose to go ahead with MIRROR - it's a lot easier to implement. I really appreciate the API reference and the suggested APIs which have made my job a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

You can get a list of method names, find the one you want and invoke it.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very helpful link & your quick response! I have used MIRROR as suggested by missingfaktor as it makes my code more readable (and easier) but this background is essential for me to understand the inner workings of reflection.

Answer (score 0):

what is "names of all the objects in the flowchart"?
Do you have some HashMap which stores objects by their names? If so, just get an object by its name and call its methods directly, without any reflection.

Comment: Thanks Alexei - I was referring to a LinkedList containing Strings of the object names. I got the answer I needed to move forward (see answers above) but I appreciate your help :-)